# How to find words in a table?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures

This is a coding exercise. Suppose there is a table of letters and a number of words. I have to find positions of the words in the table. A word may begin anywhere in the table and may be oriented either vertically of horizontally. (We can assume that a row/column may contain only one word).

For example:

```
table = xabcx
        xxxdx
        xxfex

words = ["abc", "edc", "fe"]

expected output is (0,1), (2,3), (2,2)
```

The straightforward solution is to loop over all rows/columns and check if each row/column contains any of the words. It takes `O(number of columns * number of rows * number of words * word length)`. Is there a better solution? Maybe I should pre-process the words list to build a more efficient data structure?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Trie data structure to store the table. Look up of words is very easy once you have the Trie.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a binary tree structure for the table. This is basically what most major relational database systems use anyways. In this case, you could balance the tree based on some integer hash code created from the word. Then when searching, create a hash from the search term and intelligently traverse your tree until you find the row that matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach.

You're only looking for exact matches, so I would think you should immediately be considering hash based algorithms as opposed to tree-based. First consider a hash-map that relates each letter of the alphabet to it's positions in the table. Now for each word, you look at the first letter and then traverse the table (left, right, up, down) to see if the whole word exists.

You can improve on this, by instead creating a hash-map for every two letter combination (only 676 keys) for every direction (left, right, up, down). Now you start by checking the first two letters of your word and the hash map immediately gives you locactions where those two letters exist. You can now continue to look in the table in that direction to see if the word is completed. Alternatively - you can take the next two letters of the word and see if there is a location for that letter pair that is adjacent to the first letter pair and has the same direction.

You can improve on this further... by considering a hash-map for every three letter combination for every direction. You should be able to find a good balance between storage requirements and performance, based on heuristics such as average word length.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) on every column/row takes only *O*(`number of columns * number of rows + length of patterns + number of output matches`).